# Setting the SendAs via python gmail api returns "Custom display name disallowed"

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I can't find any results when searching Google for this response.

I'm using the current Google Python API Client to make requests against the Gmail API. I can successfully insert a label, I can successfully retrieve a user's SendAs settings, but I cannot update, patch, or create a SendAS without receiving this error.

Here's a brief snippit of my code:

    `sendAsResource = {"sendAsEmail": "existingalias@test.com",
        "isDefault": True,
        "replyToAddress": "existingalias@test.com",
        "displayName": "Test Sendas",
        "isPrimary": False,
        "treatAsAlias": False
        }
    self.service.users().settings().sendAs().create(userId = "me", body=sendAsResource).execute()`

The response I get is:

`<HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/settings/sendAs?alt=json returned "Custom display name disallowed">`

I've tried `userId="me"` as well as the user i'm authenticated with, both result in this error. I am using a service account with domain wide delegation. Since adding a label works fine, I'm confused why this doesn't.

All pip modules are up to date as of this morning (google-api-python-client==1.5.3)

Edit: After hours of testing I decided to try on another user and this worked fine. There is something unique about my initial test account.

Comment: Are you an admin for the Google Apps account?  If so, if you visit the Admin console and go to "Apps" -> "Google Apps" -> "Gmail" -> "User Settings" (https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?pli=1&fral=1#ServiceSettings/service=email&subtab=filters), and look for "End User Settings" section and "Name format" field, what does it show for the "Allow users to customize this setting" checkbox?  Was it toggled recently?

Comment: That did it, thanks!

Comment: It is a bug.  In the UI, the "Allow users to customize this setting" field only affects the name for the user's primary address and not their custom send-as aliases.  Toggling the setting is a workaround until the API problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the Gmail API.  It is fixed now.